# python class file context manager

Tags: python, with-statement

I am trying to open a file in a class and close it on exit in this manner.

```py
class PlanetaryImage(object):
    @classmethod
    def open(cls, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            return cls(fp, filename)

    def __init__(self, stream, filename=None, memory_layout='DISK'):
        self.filename = filename
        self._parse_data(stream)

    def _parse_data(self, stream):
        data_stream = stream
        try:
            if self.data_filename is not None:
                dirpath = os.path.dirname(self.filename)
                data_file = os.path.abspath(
                    os.path.join(dirpath, self.data_filename))

                data_stream = open(data_file, 'rb')

            data_stream.seek(self.start_byte)
            if self.format in self.BAND_STORAGE_TYPE:
                return getattr(self, self.BAND_STORAGE_TYPE[self.format])(data_stream)

            raise Exception('Unkown format (%s)' % self.format)

        finally:
            data_stream.close()
```

There are certain cases where I am having to use open one more file in `_parse_data` function. I wanted to use `with` but the `if` statements make it difficult. Any suggestions on how to make the try section more pythonic.

Comment: You can't use `with` across code blocks. `fp` is closed as soon as `PlanetaryImage.open` returns. If you want `fp` to remain open over a longer period, you need to close it manually at the appropriate time.

Comment: I dont the know the exact reason but `fp` doesnt seem to be closing. I am able to access the stream in other methods

Comment: Do you actually use `PlanetaryImage.open` anywhere?

Comment: I just edited the code.. I call all functions that need the stream in __init__ itself may be the context for `with` then happens to be the `__init__` ?

Comment: I use it in this way `PlanetaryImage.open(filename)`

Comment: why you need to open the file twice? it's duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for `_parse_data` to try to open a file. It should be the caller's responsibility to either use `PlanetaryImage.open` with a file name or to provide an open file handle to `__init__`. `_parse_data` should do just one thing: parse the data from its stream argument.

```
class PlanetaryImage(object):
    @classmethod
    def open(cls, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            return cls(fp, filename)

    def __init__(self, stream, memory_layout='DISK'):
        self._parse_data(stream)

    def _parse_data(self, data_stream):
        try:        
            data_stream.seek(self.start_byte)
            if self.format in self.BAND_STORAGE_TYPE:
                return getattr(self, self.BAND_STORAGE_TYPE[self.format])(data_stream)

            raise Exception('Unkown format (%s)' % self.format)

        finally:
            data_stream.close()
```

Now, there are simply two options for using the class:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
    x = PlanetaryImage(fp)
    ...
```

or

```
x = PlanetaryImage(filename)
....
```

Comment: You are right about that.. The problem is the `if` section in `parse_data` function. The `self.data_filename` is a property that says whether I need to open a new file or not (the openend file usually points to another file for some cases). This is the reason behind the try finally block

Comment: Being able to open a file in a third location (in addition to externally and in `PlanetaryImage.open`) is an unnecessary complication. Your problem goes away by removing the `if` statement altogether and just ensuring that the correct file-like object is passed to `_parse_data` in the first place, and you haven't offered a compelling reason why you need to keep it; there certainly is no reason given the code you have posted.

Comment: May be this will give a better idea https://github.com/planetarypy/planetaryimage/pull/12

Comment: It doesn't. Anything you need to do to ensure the correct file is opened can be done in `__init__`, so that `_parse_data` can assume it has been given the correct file-like object.